# while loop and static variable

Tags: c

This is the code from where I was studying static variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function declaration */
void func(void);

static int count = 5; /* global variable */

main() {

   while(count--) {
      func();
   }

   return 0;
}

/* function definition */
void func( void ) {

   static int i = 5; /* local static variable */
   i++;

   printf("i is %d and count is %d\n", i, count);
}
```

I compiled and ran this on terminal and got this output

```
i is 6 and count is 4
i is 7 and count is 3
i is 8 and count is 2
i is 9 and count is 1
i is 10 and count is 0
```

My query is why did the loop stopped when the value of `count` equals to `0`? Why it's not going towards negative infinity?

Comment: Maybe see what `while(0)` does?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while

Comment: Look for the definition of `while` loop. It goes until condition is `false` or `0`.

Comment: btw it is rather irrelevant for the question wether `count`  is `static`. You would get exactly same result with `int count = 5;`

Answer (score 4):

Because `0` is equal to `false` value.

When count become equals `0`, `while` condition become `false`.

Answer (score 0):

because in your code you wrote

```
while (count--)
```

and in C true is defined as anything other than 0 and false is defined as zero. Your while loop stops when the count reaches zero.

Answer (score 0):

when your loop reaches 0, it stops because in the while loop it is counted as a false Boolean value, and so it will stop.

Answer (score 0):

**While()** will be execute when the value is `true`. In this case, any positive number is treated as `true`. Zero is on the other hand interpreted as `false`, thus stopping the loop.

Basically `While(true)`, do something. Once you reach `false`, the **while()** loop stops.

If you want to go negative, then you'll need a **for()** loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 10; i > -10; i--)
    {
        printf("%d", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you want to use **while()**, you should do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int position = 10;

    while(position > -10)
    {
        printf("%d", position);
        position--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "**Need** to use for loop", why? It may be more idiomatic, but using `while` works just as well: `while(i > -10) { printf(...); --i; }`

Comment: True, I extended my answer.

Comment: Your code has a minor problem: it will print the numbers without a space between them: `10987654....`.

Comment: Is that a problem? :) the code is there to show how this works, is not there to print out  and  ;) Then it is up to you to format the output however you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 == false
```

And when

```
while (0)
```

Then the loop will stop.

---

Since you tagged the post with `c++` too, I will give you an example in c++ using [`boolalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha), where the bool values are extracted and represented as either `true` or `false`:

```
bool b = -5;
cout << boolalpha << b; // outputs: true
```

And now:

```
bool b = 0;
cout << boolalpha << b; // outputs: false
```

Comment: you should explain what `boolalpha` does, otherwise the example might be rather confusing than clarifying

Answer (score 0):

The while loop runs until its argument is different from "false", which is 0. So when count equals 0, it stops.